# How to press Enter using PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

please tell me how to press the Enter button using the PyAutoGUI library. I've tried everything, but nothing is pressed. Can you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer

```
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

or

```
pyautogui.write('\n')
```

[source](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-write-function)

If not working, could be because the mouse cursor is not on the desired place, maybe you would need to first click over the app you want to enter with for example `pyautogui.click(100, 200);` where (100,200) are the X,Y coordinates of screen, you will need to locate where do you need that enter.

For more details, you could see [this](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/)

Comment: You can't control the mouse there. When I press the Alt + Tab key combination, it switches to the application that I need. but the mouse goes behind this window and does not click anything.

Answer (score 4):

Use `pyautogui.press(“enter”)` or `pyautogui.hotkey(“enter”)`

for pressing 3 times:
use `pyautogui.press(“enter”, presses=3)`
or

```
for i in range(3):
    pyautogui.press(“enter”)
```

for pressing lots of keys:

```
pyautogui.press([“enter”, “shift”])
```

or

```
for key in [“enter”, “shift”]:
    pyautogui.press(key)
```

dispatch user holding down the key until keyup:

```
pyautogui.keyDown(“enter”)
```

and for keyup:

```
pyautogui.keyUp(“enter”)
```

and also one thing, if you’re used keyDown, you can still use `pyautogui.press(“enter”)` too :D

If you want to know more go to https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. If it helps to find a solution, then I will say that I am trying to click in the main menu of a game in which the mouse cannot be controlled. Of course there is another game but you can control the mouse there, but I would like to control it from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

on windows I could never get Pyautogui key presses to work. I had to use pywinauto instead. I would still use pyautogui for finding images and typing our characters but used pywinauto to press keys.

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
send_keys('{ENTER}')
```

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like you,but i solved it by turning the keyboard language from Chinese to English ,so the enter_press is useful to send message but not write message

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

This wasn't working:
`pyautogui.write('enter')`

But this worked:
`pyautogui.write(['enter'])`

I'm using VS Code on Windows 10.

Cheers.